# Как добавить дополнительный текст к ng-bind-html?

Tags: angularjs

Есть такой HTML, который преобразует и выводит текст в контейнер `div` за счет фильтров:

```
 <div ng-bind-html="message.message | hrefConvert | rawHtml | test"></div>
```

Можно ли в `ng-bind-html` передать еще один объект `message.file`, чтобы его обработал фильтр test и возвратил к сообщению в блоке - дополнительный текст?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div ng-bind-html="(message.message | hrefConvert | rawHtml | test) + (message.file | test)"></div>
```